# Key value pair as a param in a console app

Tags: c#, command-line, parameters, console-application

Is there an easy way to allow a collection of Key/Value pairs (both strings) as command line parameters to a console app?

Comment: Do you mean command line parameters?

Comment: Yes I do mean Command Line params.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you mean having a commandline looking like this:
c:> YourProgram.exe /switch1:value1 /switch2:value2 ...

This can easily be parsed on startup with something looking like this:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Regex cmdRegEx = new Regex(@"/(?<name>.+?):(?<val>.+)");

   Dictionary<string, string> cmdArgs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
   foreach (string s in args)
   {
      Match m = cmdRegEx.Match(s);
      if (m.Success)
      {
         cmdArgs.Add(m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value);
      }
   }
}
```

You can then do lookups in cmdArgs dictionary. Not sure if that's what you want though.

Answer (score 8):

There is no good way to precisely pass key/value pairs from command-line. The only thing that's available is an array of string which you can loop through and extract as key/value pairs.

```
using System;

public class Class1
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>();

      // hopefully you have even number args count.
      for(int i=0; i < args.Length; i+=2){
      {
           values.Add(args[i], args[i+1]);
      }

   }
}
```

and then call

> Class1.exe key1 value1 key2 value2

Answer (score 3):

The entry point of an application is a `main` method that can take a `string[]` of the arguments (these are the command line arguments).

This can't be changed. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx).

To make working with this easier, there are many command line helper libraries that can be used.

One such library is [.NET CLI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dotnetcli/), from the MONO guys, and [many](http://commandline.codeplex.com/) [others](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/ccmdline.aspx).