# How to pass key value pairs from console app to a Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

I want to pass some arguments from my app like so:

```
app.exe mode=1 thread=single
```

and I want to convert these to a Dictionary of key-value pairs. Any one-line suggestions?

Comment: http://mitch-wheat.blogspot.com.au/2013/02/parsing-command-line-arguments.html

Comment: Can there be any amount of key-value pairs, or always just two?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is very basic and doesn't take error conditions into account:

```
var dictionary = args.Select(a => a.Split('='))
                     .ToDictionary(a => a[0], a => a.Length == 2 ? a[1] : null);
```

Some of the potential errors are:

- Duplicate names
- More than one `=`

Dealing with those makes it a little uglier:

```
var dictionary = args.Select(a => a.Split(new [] {'='}, 2))
                     .GroupBy(a => a[0], a => a.Length == 2 ? a[1] : null)
                     .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: You did ask for a one-line suggestion.

Comment: To be honest, I think Mitch Wheats will probably serve you better, but he doesn't seem to want to post it as an actual answer.

Comment: I have enough rep. I was just trying to help the poster.

Comment: The link will be there at Blogger at least as long as SO is here!

Answer (score 4):

The link Mitch [shared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16540640/how-to-pass-key-value-pairs-from-console-app-to-a-dictionary/16540914#comment23756497_16540640) to his blog post [Parsing Command Line Arguments](http://mitch-wheat.blogspot.com.au/2013/02/parsing-command-line-arguments.html) provides the answer you're probably looking for.

It contains a class that can be used to parse command line args into a `Dictionary` of key/value pairs.

```
/// <summary>
/// Very basic Command Line Args extracter
/// <para>Parse command line args for args in the following format:</para>
/// <para>/argname:argvalue /argname:argvalue ...</para>
/// </summary>
public class CommandLineArgs
{    
    private const string Pattern = @"\/(?<argname>\w+):(?<argvalue>.+)";    
    private readonly Regex _regex = new Regex(
        Pattern,
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.Compiled);
    private readonly Dictionary<String, String> _args = 
        new Dictionary<String, String>();

    public CommandLineArgs()
    {
        BuildArgDictionary();
    }

    public string this[string key]
    {
        get 
        {
            return _args.ContainsKey(key) ? _args[key] : null;
        }
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(string key)
    {
        return _args.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    private void BuildArgDictionary()
    {
        var args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
        foreach (var match in args.Select(arg => 
                    _regex.Match(arg)).Where(m => m.Success))
        {
            try
            {
                 _args.Add(
                      match.Groups["argname"].Value,
                      match.Groups["argvalue"].Value);
            }
            // Ignore any duplicate args
            catch (Exception) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @MitchWheat, you should post your own answer, feel free to copy. Then I shall delete and upvote. Feel free to link your blog in the answer but the content needs to get onto SO. Thats how SO works.

Comment: @MitchWheat, if you wish to enforce your copyright I will delete immeadiately?

Answer (score 0):

I did delete this, but I'm going to leave it here just because the OP *did* ask for a "one line suggestion". :)

```
var result = (from item in data.Split(' ') let keyValue = item.Split('=') select new {Key = keyValue[0], Value = keyValue[1]}).ToDictionary(item => item.Key, item => item.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all existing answers to both this question and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955456/key-value-pair-as-a-param-in-a-console-app)

The original question here asks for a one-line answer, so here one is.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> cmdArgs = args.Select(s => new Regex(@"/(?<name>.+?):(?<val>.+)").Match(s)).Where(m => m.Success).ToDictionary(m => m.Groups[1].Value, m => m.Groups[2].Value);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Not a one-liner, but a somewhat readable solution I use for arguments formatted like:

-arg1 bla -arg2 ble

```
var argsDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var argKeys = args.Where(a => a.StartsWith("-")).ToArray();
foreach (var argKey in argKeys)
{
    var keyIndex = Array.IndexOf(args, argKey);
    var argValue = e.Args.ElementAtOrDefault(keyIndex + 1);

    try
    {
        args.Add(argKey, argValue);
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Startup arguments invalid.");
        return;
    }
}
```